# Testing dictionary entries in a Pandas lambda function

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, lambda

When I do:

```
​df['ViewClass'] = df['dataset_id'].apply(
    lambda x: classdict[str(x)] if classdict[str(x)] else '???' )
```

This blows up if the key does not exist.  How can I get get the lambda function to behave and put in `'???'` if the key does not exist?

I come from a Perl background and that accounts for my faulty first try here :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are looking for Series.map:

```
df['ViewClass'] = df['dataset_id'].astype(str).map(classdict).fillna('???')
```

`.astype(str)` converts the column to object. Then `.map` looks up the corresponding values in the dictionary. It returns `nan` if it cannot find the key. Therefore, at the end you'll fill `nan`s with the specified value.

It is generally better to use vectorized methods like `map` instead of iterating over a Series or a DataFrame (that is what apply does).

Answer (score 6):

Use the `dict.get()` method as:

```
classdict.get(str(x), '???')
```

Answer (score 1):

In terms of python basics, to test if `str(x)` is in `classdict`, use

```
str(x) in classdict
```

i.e. the lambda would be

```
lambda x: classdict[str(x)] if str(x) in classdict else '???'
```

For this application, the other solutions are better though.

Comment: I see,  Perl uses the shortcut of just testing classdict[someentry] that led to my problem.